# Spark Structured Streaming left outer joins returns outer nulls for already matched rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Im basically using the example given in Spark's the [documentation here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#outer-joins-with-watermarking) with the built-in test stream in which one stream is ahead by 3 seconds (was originally using kafka but ran into the same issue). The results returned the match columns correctly, however after a while the same key is returned with an outer null.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to exclude the duplicate outer null results when there was a match?

Code:

```
val testStream = session.readStream.format("rate")
  .option("rowsPerSecond", "5").option("numPartitions", "1").load()

val impressions = testStream
  .select(
    (col("value") + 15).as("impressionAdId"),
    col("timestamp").as("impressionTime"))

val clicks = testStream
  .select(
    col("value").as("clickAdId"),
    col("timestamp").as("clickTime"))


// Apply watermarks on event-time columns
val impressionsWithWatermark =
  impressions.withWatermark("impressionTime", "20 seconds")
val clicksWithWatermark =
  clicks.withWatermark("clickTime", "30 seconds")

// Join with event-time constraints
val result = impressionsWithWatermark.join(
  clicksWithWatermark,
  expr("""
clickAdId = impressionAdId AND
clickTime >= impressionTime AND
clickTime <= impressionTime + interval 10 seconds
"""),
  joinType = "leftOuter"      // can be "inner", "leftOuter", "rightOuter"
)

val query = result.writeStream.outputMode("update").format("console").option("truncate", false).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 19
-------------------------------------------
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
|impressionAdId|impressionTime         |clickAdId|clickTime              |
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
|100           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.362|100      |2018-05-23 22:18:41.362|
|101           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.562|101      |2018-05-23 22:18:41.562|
|102           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.762|102      |2018-05-23 22:18:41.762|
|103           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.962|103      |2018-05-23 22:18:41.962|
|104           |2018-05-23 22:18:39.162|104      |2018-05-23 22:18:42.162|
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 57
-------------------------------------------
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
|impressionAdId|impressionTime         |clickAdId|clickTime              |
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
|290           |2018-05-23 22:19:16.362|290      |2018-05-23 22:19:19.362|
|291           |2018-05-23 22:19:16.562|291      |2018-05-23 22:19:19.562|
|292           |2018-05-23 22:19:16.762|292      |2018-05-23 22:19:19.762|
|293           |2018-05-23 22:19:16.962|293      |2018-05-23 22:19:19.962|
|294           |2018-05-23 22:19:17.162|294      |2018-05-23 22:19:20.162|
|100           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.362|null     |null                   |
|99            |2018-05-23 22:18:38.162|null     |null                   |
|103           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.962|null     |null                   |
|101           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.562|null     |null                   |
|102           |2018-05-23 22:18:38.762|null     |null                   |
+--------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately looks like you're hitting correctness issue [SPARK-26154](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26154) which [patch](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23634) is available but review is dragged a bit.

Given the patch is a bit huge, you might not want to try out porting back the patch to your version manually. Then I think your best bet is asking committers to review the patch sooner, as well as asking for porting back to the version line what you use.